# Override method with unwanted superclass argument

Tags: java, superclass, overriding

I have a interface Vector from a library that I use in my project and I cannot modify...

```
interface Vector<T> {
   public Vector<T> plus(Vector<T> v);
}
```

Then I implemented it with a class `FourVector` but the problem arise in overriding method plus. I want `FourVector` may add only with `FourVector`, not with all types of Vector! What I try to do is a thing like this (but is obviously wrong)

```java
class FourVector<T> implements Vector<T> {
   public Vector<T>  plus(FourVector<T> v) {
   ...
   }
}
```

There is some pattern or a workaround that permits the realization of this idea?

Comment: So is FourVector a 4-dimensional vector? If so, how can you know which dimensions to add to when you add a 2D vector to it?

Comment: Yes it represent Minkowski 4-dimensional vector. Infact, I want to prevent this type of inconsistencies in overriding methods...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a `Vector<T>`, you will be able at compile time to pass any types of `Vector<T>` to its `add` method. That is how the interface is designed.

So your `FourVector` is not a real `Vector` in that respect:

- either you accept that and don't implement `Vector`
- or you can add a runtime check: `if (!(v instanceof FourVector)) throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Only FourVector allowed here");`

Answer (score 0):

I'll improve first correct comment.

On the other hand you are allowed to override method in the following way:

```
@Override
public FourVector<T> plus(Vector<T> v) {
    return null;
}
```

You need to realize that interface was defined using the signature. You also need to realize that your suggested behavior would be very confusing. Just look at following code:

```
public void a() {
    Vector<T> vector = new FourVector<>();
    b(vector);
}

public void b(Vector<T> v) {
    v.plus(new ThreeVector<T>());
}
```

How would the developer know that even even if property is type of `Vector` within method `b`, it's `FourVector` in fact and the method `plus` accepts `FourVector`'s only. Method `b` would somehow know the exact type of given property.  But it's apparently against suggest purpose of generic method in generic interface.